# Node.js nodemon on windows doesn't watch nested dirs?

Tags: node.js

Node.js 0.8.1

Should nodemon on windows watch nested dirs for file changes?

It does not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
This was fixed in [3c885ff](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/commit/3c885ff3a8333075b4d8965e904ea48438ae63c4)

Try updating your version of nodemon?

`npm update nodemon` should do the trick, unless in your package.json you've specified a version.
Current version is 0.6.19

Comment: Hi, I run 0.6.23. I can use --watch key to point out the directories, but It seems that I didn't need to that before. What about using .nodemonignore file?

Comment: do you have a nodemonignore file?

Comment: Now Yes, first I've tried without it. Its it right to always have it?

Comment: Can do, not necessary though. I don't in most of my projects. Shouldn't affect watching subdirs though?

Comment: If I add nodemonignore and ignore some dirs (like /.git, /.idea, /test) - it watches all other dirs on all levels. If I don't have ignore file it watches only root dir.